# How to call a method on Google App Engine from C#

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

I Have an application in my account and I want to call a method that takes int number and return one int number (int someMethod(int someVar)) from client application that must be written in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(Your method URL);
```

You can URL using some program like [HTTP Analyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/index.html).

```
wr.Headers.add(headerName, value); //the same as in HTTP Analyzer show;      

WebResponse response =  wr.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 4):

All that you have to do to call a method in an AppEngine application is to expose it as a URL that your app handles. Your C# application can use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx) to make a request to that URL.